# How do I set my local git identity?

Tags: git

This is my first setup of a repo on GitHub. I am running Linux, and my GitHub account has ssh-keys setup for my computer.

When I try to run `git commit`, I get this error.

```
git commit -m "examples"
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'j0h@sx.(none)')
j0h@sx:~/Learning-OpenCV-3_examples$   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

What I do not understand is which name(s) and identity this is asking for when it says `git config --global user.name "Your Name"` does that mean the name on my PC? Or my GitHub username? Or my email username? Or something else?

I have tried a variety of combinations, but I still cannot commit via the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues here:

#### Setting Your Git Identity

First, your identity should be simply your full name and email address which *could* be your GitHub username and email combo. But this is not a verification stage as much as a “tag” to identify you; this has nothing to do directly with your GitHub username unless they are indeed one and the same.

So perhaps your version of those commands would be:

```
git config --global user.email "j0h@example.com"
git config --global user.name "jOh"
```

And then check those values like this:

```
git config -l
```

Output should be something like this; modified version of my own output for that command so the `credential.helper` and `core.editor` settings might be different for you:

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=jOh
user.email=j0h@example.com
core.editor=nano
```

#### Adding Files and Making a Commit

But then you say this:

> When I try to run git commit, I get this error.
>
> ```
> git commit -m "examples"
> ```

Well, that command is missing the `-a` which is an alias for `--all` which means the following according to the `man` page for [`git-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

So the command would be:

```
git commit -a -m "examples"
```

And if you have not already added files to the repository, you would run `git add` for the specific file:

```
git add [filename]
```

Or maybe just use a wildcard to get all files set:

```
git add *
```

And then run the `git commit` command like this:

```
git commit -a -m "examples"
```

Comment: Huge relief, its working now. I was confused by the argument list style user.name.. thanks for clarifying.